# kate does not save the view / border settings?

Tags: kde, kate

When I run kate (from kde) it doesn't save the view / borders I set.  I set line numbers and turn off the minimap.   Then exit kate, run again, back to where I have to set the line numbers and disable the minimap.

Any hints on what I need to do for it to keep the setting?

Answer (score 0):

The view menu changes are temporary. To set the default go to `Settings / Configure Kate / Appearance / Borders Tab`.